# How can I show that the one-dimensional wave equation (with a constant propagation velocity $c$) is not invariant under Galilean transformation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

The one-dimensional wave equation is given by

[image: wave equation]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written down the Galiean transformation $x=x'-vt'$, $t=t'$ and used the chain rule to change variables from $x,t$ to $x',t'$?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28912/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Galilean transformation of the wave equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28912/)

Comment: @mikestone I don't understand why we need to change the variables, what would I need to show mathematically?